# Lat/longs for multiple addresses using google api

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

How can I improve this code to accept a file that contains a lot of addresses and pass it as a parameter to Google API to get lat/longs?

Right now it's an example to return lat/long of one address but I want to automate for multiple addresses from a dataset.

```
import requests

GOOGLE_MAPS_API_URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'

params = {
    'address': '100 FOUNDERS CV ,ALPHARETTA, GA,30022',
    'sensor': 'false',
    'region': 'USA'
}

# Do the request and get the response data
req = requests.get(GOOGLE_MAPS_API_URL, params=params)
res = req.json()

# Use the first result
result = res['results'][0]

geodata = dict()
geodata['lat'] = result['geometry']['location']['lat']
geodata['lng'] = result['geometry']['location']['lng']
geodata['address'] = result['formatted_address']

print('{address}. (lat, lng) = ({lat}, {lng})'.format(**geodata))
```

Comment: From the way this api seems to work it looks like you want to loop over all the different addresses making GET calls in every iteration to get the results and save the results in a container. If you have too many calls you might run into some kind of public api call limitation.

Comment: Do you know if any alternative way to avoid api call limitation?

Comment: Did you try the iterative approach ? Have you hit the limit ?

Comment: Yes, in fact it throttles me before 2500 limit a day and gives me same lat longs for all addresses once it throttles.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed this up by using the Google Maps Service's Python library. There's a geocode function: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/blob/master/googlemaps/geocoding.py

You can read in your file as a dict of dicts and have each line be the key to iterate through.